Populating Custom Multiselect ListBox UserControl in Code behind (C#)
I have a custom UserControl Dropdown ListBox that I need to populate with some ListItems I am retrieving from my DB.
The usercontrol in my ASPX page:
  <tr>
                <td class="standard-label">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddlchkProfession" Text="Professions:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="messageAlignLeft">
                    <ucddtb:DropdownCheckboxList ID="ddlchkProfession"  runat="server" /> 
                </td>
            </tr>

The code for the Ucontrol:
<div class="form-group col-sm-5">
    <asp:ListBox ID="ddlListBox" class="ddlchkBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
   </asp:ListBox>
</div>
                
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('[id*=ddlListBox]').multiselect({
                        includeSelectAllOption: true,
                        templates: {
                            button: '<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><span class="multiselect-selected-text"></span></button>'
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>

My current code behind logic:
 try
            {
                
                List<FormLookup> fal = DBPR.ABT.Tax.BO.FormLookup.FormLookupGetList(DBPR.ABT.Tax.BO.BoBase.MasterConnectionString);

                foreach( FormLookup listItem in fal)
                {
                    ListItem ddloption = new ListItem();
                    ddloption.Text = listItem.FormDescription;
                    ddloption.Value = listItem.FormLookupId.ToString();

                    //this.ddlchkProfession.Controls.Add(ddloption);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {

            }

I am trying to add ListItems to the Listbox in Code Behind, but I don't see any options for ddlProfession that does any such databinding in the method. I haven't much experience using these controls to actually hold data, so I am a bit lost about how to build them to actually contain data correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: I was able to achieve what I wanted to by designating my ListBox as a Listbox type in the class of my ascx.cs file...
 public ListBox ddlMultiSelectListBox {
        get { return ddlListBox; }
    } 

I was then able to access it from code-behind and bind my db results as I would any other general ListBox control..
 try
            {
                
                List<FormLookup> fal = FOO.BAR.Tax.BO.FormLookup.FormLookupGetList(foo.bar.Tax.BO.BoBase.MasterConnectionString);

                ddlchkProfession.ddlMultiSelectListBox.DataSource = fal;
                ddlchkProfession.ddlMultiSelectListBox.DataTextField = "FormDescription";
                ddlchkProfession.ddlMultiSelectListBox.DataValueField = "formLookUpId";
                ddlchkProfession.ddlMultiSelectListBox.DataBind();
                
                
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {

            }


